# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException please help find the error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following code:

```
String[] currentitem = new String[5];
currentitem = responsestring.split("%");
String[] date = new String[3];
date = currentitem[2].split(".");
String[] time = new String[3];
time = currentitem[4].split(":");
objects.add(new Print(id, currentitem[0],currentitem[1], currentitem[5],             Integer.parseInt(currentitem[3]), Integer.parseInt(date[2]), Integer.parseInt(date[1]), Integer.parseInt(date[0]), Integer.parseInt(time[0]), Integer.parseInt(time[1]), Integer.parseInt(time[2])));`
```

and i get the following error:

```
10-24 14:46:02.303    7841-7860/de.socialbit.printlog2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-646
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=2
            at de.socialbit.printlog2.NavigationDrawerFragment$requestdata.run(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:367)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I cant seem to find where the error is

Comment: the exceptions means the position that u are requesting for its outta bounds.. get it lol..now let me read question el ol el

Comment: currentItem[4] not currentItem[5] at the end of objects.add()

Comment: `I cant seem to find where the error is` <= in your code ... it is pretty obvious: `responsestring` does not look like you've expected ...

Comment: You are trying to reference an array item that doesn't exist. `currentitem` is declared with length 5, you are trying to access the sixth array item (`currentitem[5]`) which doesn't exist.

Comment: @zgc7009 i have changed it but get the error anyways

Comment: what is this location `NavigationDrawerFragment$requestdata.run(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:367)`. what code is present in the line Also wats is your `responsestring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening here:

```
date = currentitem[2].split(".");
```

If you look at the error message, you'll see it mentions that the length of the array you're playing with is 0, but you're trying to get element 2. This is the line where this occurs.

You've got your `currentitem` array arriving from this line

```
currentitem = responsestring.split("%");
```

If this is giving you a zero-length array, then that can only be because `responsestring` is empty (i.e., equal to `""`).

Part of where you're getting confused is that you're misunderstanding what's going on with lines like

```
String[] currentitem = new String[5];
currentitem = responsestring.split("%");
```

The second line here doesn't *fill* the array you created in the first line, it simply throws it away. The `.split()` method *creates* an array, rather than operating on a pre-supplied one. So the fact that you specified a length for `currentitem` is irrelevant: the `new String[5]` you created is no longer there after the `.split()` line, which will return whatever array it deems appropriate. You ought to write those two lines as just one:

```
String[] currentitem = responsestring.split("%");
```

The same is true of `date` and `time`: the arrays you create are immediately thrown away, and replaced with whatever array is returned by the `.split()` call, which might be of any length (including zero).

But the main problem seems to be that `responsestring` is empty when you're expecting it to have something in it.

Comment: yeah i understand this but date[] is declared as String[3] so it should be ok

Comment: @JonasOtto I've edited the answer to explain. Your `String[3]` is being thrown away. I've explained in terms of `currentitem` but the same principle applies.

Comment: thanks this explains everything :D